# Phase 10 skip cards

Tags: phase-10

Four people are playing Phase 10. Player 1 skips player 3. Player 2 takes their turn. Player 3 skips turn. Can player 4 pick up discard card played by player 2?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, player 4 can draw from the discard pile.

While the Skip card itself is not able to be drawn from the discard pile, there is no rule preventing a player from drawing the top discard card if discarded by players other than the previous in turn order.